# Что такое конструктор копирования в C++?

Tags: c++, конструктор-копирования

Что такое конструктор копирования в C++ и для чего он нужен? Что можно сделать с помощью конструктора копирования, почему говорят, что лучше не использовать конструкторы копирования, и что такое явный и неявный конструктор копирования?

Comment: [Почему не использовать (rule of zero)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), [остальные вопросы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конструктор копирования позволяет при создании объекта, копировать объект такого же типа или  наследника этого типа(срезание). Например:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    A(int k) : i(k) {}
    A(const A& a) { i = a.i; cout << i; }

};
struct AA : A {   
    int n{};
    AA(int c) : A(c) {} 
    //копирование по умолчанию
};
```

тип  AA  имеет `n` и, `i` своего базового типа.

```
 AA aa1(3), // явный вызов конструктора
   aa2 = 5; // не явный вызов конструктора


A a(2), // явный вызов конструктора
  a1(aa1), // явный вызов конструктора копирования(
  a2(a),   // явный вызов конструктора копирования
  a3 = a;  // Не явный вызов конструктора копирования
A a4 = aa2; // Не явный вызов конструктора копирования
```

Объекты типа `А`  создаем, копируя  данные ранее созданных объектов. При копировании производных объектов, происходит  срезка его данных, то есть копируется только  базовая часть( в данном случаи aa1.i и aa2.i).

> почему говорят, что лучше не использовать конструкторы копирования

Чтобы  не выполнить лишнее копирование, в случаях, когда нет необходимости создания нового  объекта **не встроенных типов**,  лучше просто ссылаться на них (A& refА = a или const A& crefА = a, если не нужно модифицировать объект).

А так же, для не тривиальных типов, которые могут хранить ссылки или указатели на какие то   последовательности, сложно копируемые  объекты, лучше написать конструкторы и операторы перемещения, дабы не копировать  большой объем данных, а  только представление. Это дает дополнительные возможности  при перегрузке функций  и перемещения данных(копирование только представления) временных объектов вызовом.

**Можно сказать что лучше, имея конкретную ситуацию.  В инструментах не существуют инструменты лучше или хуже _ у каждого свое предназначение. Иногда, палкой срубить сухую ветку эффективней, чем пилить пилой**.....

Answer (score 0):

https://www.bestprog.net/ru/2018/04/03/c-classes-part-2-copy-constructor-examples-of-using-passing-a-class-object-to-a-function-returning-a-class-from-a-function_ru/

> Конструктор копирования – это специальный конструктор, который
> позволяет получить идентичный к заданному объект. То есть, с помощью
> конструктора копирования можно получить копию уже существующего
> объекта. Конструктор копирования еще называется инициализатором копии
> (copy initializer). Конструктор копирования должен получать входным
> параметром константную ссылку (&) на объект такого же класса.
>
> Конструктор копирования вызывается в случаях, когда нужно получить
> полную копию объекта. В C++ полная копия объекта нужна в трех случаях.
>
> Случай 1. В момент объявления нового объекта и его инициализации
> данными другого объекта с помощью оператора =. Следующий фрагмент кода
> демонстрирует данную ситуацию для некоторого класса ClassName
>
> ```
> // объявление экземпляра (объекта) класса ClassName
> ClassName obj1;
>
> // объявление объекта obj2 с одновременной инициализацией данными объекта obj2
> ClassName obj2 = obj1; // вызывается конструктор копирования
> ```
>
> В этом случае нужно скопировать данные из объекта obj1 в объект obj2.
> То есть, нужно создать копию объекта obj1 так, чтобы этот объект мог в
> дальнейшем корректно использоваться в программе. Поэтому нужна копия.
> Этим занимается конструктор копирования.
>
> Случай 2. Когда нужно передать объект в функцию как параметр-значение.
> В этом случае создается полная копия объекта.
>
> Случай 3. Когда нужно вернуть объект из функции по значению. В этом
> случае также создается полная копия объекта.

Comment: Если копипастите чужой текст в ответ, пожалуйста, добавляйте ссылку на источник.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения. Про это забыл.

Comment: Если копипастите чужой текст в ответ, то убедитесь, что он корректный.